# My program tells me that my method is undefined for my type what does that mean?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I wrote a code that is supposed to take an array and sort it from smallest value to largest, but I get an error. this is the code

```
public class minHeapify{
    public static void exchange(int a[],int i,int j) {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }
    public static int parent(int i) {
        return (int) Math.floor((i - 1)/2);
    }
    public static int left(int i) {
        return 2*i + 1;
    }
    public static int right(int i) {
        return 2*(i+1);
    }
    public minHeapify(int a[], int start,int end) {
        int l = left(start); int r = right(start);
        int smallest;
        if(l >= end){
            smallest = (a[l] < a[start])? l: start;
        }
        if(r >= end){
            smallest = (a[r] < a[smallest])? r: smallest;
        }
        if(smallest != start) {
            exchange(a,start,smallest);
            minHeapify(a,smallest,end);
        }
    }
}
```

the error that I get is " The method minHeapify(int[], int, int) is undefined for the type minHeapify" and im not sure what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the method has the same name as the class and has no return type. Therefore, from the compiler's point of view, it's a constructor rather than an ordinary method. And a constructor can't call itself in the manner your method is trying to.

Rename the method and add a return type. If the method needs to be automatically invoked upon construction, simply call it from the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Java thinks that `public minHeapify(int a[], int start,int end)` is a constructor, not a normal method. You can fix it by respecting the convention that class names are uppercase: `public class MinHeapify`.